# Circle Ci failed to start event processor

Tags: docker, ubuntu, circleci

Just followed this to check a demo https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/local-cli/#running-a-job

```
git clone https://github.com/CircleCI-Public/circleci-demo-go.git
cd circleci-demo-go
circleci local execute --job build
```

But first I got this error

> Error: Unable to validate config: Post "https://circleci.com/graphql-unstable": dial tcp: lookup circleci.com on 127.0.0.53:53: server misbehaving

On the next try it shows me this error

> Error: failed to connect to docker; please ensure that docker is running, and that `docker version` succeeds

for the next try I used sudo user like this `sudo circleci local execute --job build`
this time also I got another error.

> Error: failed to start event processor: failed to compute task config: failed to read config file: read /tmp/local_build_config.yml: is a directory

**Ubuntu 20**
may its some thing around docker as I got this error when running `docker version`

```
docker version
Client:
 Version:           20.10.8
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.16.6
 Git commit:        3967b7d28e
 Built:             Wed Aug  4 21:24:10 2021
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/version": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

WHAT I SHOULD DO TO RUN CIRCLE CI SUCCESSFULLY?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your user to the docker group. Try this command:

```
sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER
```

Log out and log back again

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Circle CI and Docker.

If those are installed using snap run - `sudo snap remove circleci docker`

Then install Circle CI using:

```
curl -fLSs https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CircleCI-Public/circleci-cli/master/install.sh | bash
```

Install Docker from https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

Then run - `circleci setup` if your circle ci needs personal access token

Finally run `circleci local execute --job build`

Worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.